# Is there a way to "hide" merge commits in GitHub, when comparing branches?

Tags: git, github

My team of 10 or so are using GitHub for our development project. We have a main `develop` branch from which we create feature branches to do our development tasks, and then we merge the feature branches back to `develop`. We use Pull Requests to do code reviews. All standard stuff.

However, one thing has been bothering me.

Say developer A creates a feature branch named `myFeature`. In this branch, he makes a one-line change to a single file, say `Loop.java`.

In the meantime, 100 unrelated commits are merged to `develop` from other branches, by other developers.

Now, before developer A pushes his changes and issues a pull request, he wants to make sure his changes work with the latest `develop` branch. Thus, he merges the HEAD of `develop` into his branch:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout myFeature
git merge develop
# testing and stuff
git push origin myFeature
```

The last command (`git merge develop`) always results in a new commit. Thus, when developer A pushes his changes and issues a Pull Request for `myFeature`, the reviewer of the Pull Request will see 101 commits added to branch `myFeature`: one has the change to `Loop.java`, and the other 100 are unrelated and have already in fact been merged in `develop`. Here they only serve as noise to disguise what was really changed by developerA in this branch.

**Is there an easy way for the reviewer to tell what was changed by just developer's A changes, and somehow "hide" the commits that came from the merge with `develop`?** I'm specifically thinking about the "Files Changed" tab in the Pull Request view.
(I realize that I could use the "Commits" tab, and step through all the commits one by one to see what was changed, but this can be tiresome if there are lots of commits. I like the singular, final view of the "Files Changed" tab.)

**EDIT**: `git rebase develop` has been proposed as an option, but I don't think it's appropriate for our purposes. Often, multiple developers will be working on `myFeature`, so rebase has the potential to mess everyone up since it rewrites the history.

**EDIT 2**: As @kan kindly pointed out below, GitHub is actually behaving nicely: yes, it will show the merge commit in the "Commits" tab of the Pull Request (which is perfectly fine), but under the "Files Changed" tab, only the files changed on this feature branch (and not those from the merge) are listed. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If A's `myFeature` branch was branched from `develop`, and he merged in the latest changes from `develop`, I don't think hundreds of extra commits should appear in GitHub, I think it should only be the commits that are unique to that branch.  Is A doing a pull request into the wrong branch, like into `master` instead of develop?

Comment: @ColdHawaiian: No, A is branching from `develop` and then merging `develop`, and then doing a pull request to merge into `develop`. That's why I was confused, too.

Comment: Another possibility is that A's version of develop history has already been modified (ie the commit shas are different on corresponding commits). Maybe A's commits have already been rewritten with a `rebase`, `cherry-pick`, or `commit --amend`?  Is A using Git from the command line, or a gui like GitHub for Windows?  GitHub for Windows does weird stuff with rebasing implicitly.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian: No, it's nothing complicated like that. We're using the command line on Ubuntu, and not using `rebase` or anything.  I'm able to recreate the scenario on a test repository, doing very simple commits and changes: I'll make a new branch `myFeature`, make a change, and commit and push. I'll look on GitHub and can see the single commit on `myFeature`. Then I'll checkout `develop`, make an unrelated change, and commit. Then I'll checkout `myFeature` again, and `git merge develop`, and then push. I look on GitHub, at the compare view for branch `myFeature`, and it lists both commits.

Answer (score 7):

One method would be rather than doing `git merge` is to `git rebase develop`.  This will not cause the merge commit to occur and place the new commit at the end of new commits in develop.

The histories should then only show the one new commit as changed in the pull request.   IMO this also keeps the history pretty linear and easier to follow.

Comment: From what I've read (including from @kan below), `git rebase` isn't a good idea if the feature branch has already been pushed to the remote servers, since other developers may have also pulled the branch. Is that true? Also, how does rebase deal with merge conflicts?

Comment: Yes that is true.  As that will rewrite the history that has been pushed out.  The way that rebase works is that git rolls back to where the branches have diverged, brings in the changes from the remote and applies the rolled back commits one at a time.  So when a conflict occurs, you will then modify the commit before proceeding.  Because of this changing of history, you want to be careful with it.

Comment: @doofuslarge Yes, it basically means that all developers which got the branch also should do rebases. If you carefully read `git help rebase` they describe it as "ripple effect". The gerrit introduces a notion of changesets, which allows to to deal with it in more elegant way.

Comment: @kan Thanks for your suggestion and help. For now, I think rebasing is not appropriate for our workflow, due to the ripple effect. So it looks like I'll just have to live with the problem above.

Comment: @doofuslarge One thing I don't like that you call it "the problem". It is not a problem, it is more proper reflection of a history - what did actually happen.

Comment: @kan I'm sorry you don't like the world "problem". Maybe I should have said that it's an "inconvenience" for me, and unintuitive. It seems to me that when we're comparing a branch with `develop`, then the commits  to `develop` (which were merged into the branch) shouldn't be shown.

Comment: @doofuslarge All merged commits are actually in the branch after the merge. So, it does exactly what it says on the tin. You could just properly specify revision lists to show that you want. If I understand you correctly, you should add `^develop`, see "gitrevisions" documentation for more details.

Comment: @kan Interesting. Thanks for the pointer. As far as you know, can I do something like this in GitHub, to compare two branches, or on a Pull Request? I couldn't seem to find a way.

Comment: @doofuslarge I am not sure about that exactly you are trying to do. If you merge branch X into a branch Y it means all is in the branch Y now. If later you are merging Y into another branch Z, then everything will be merged, and diff will show everything. So, why do you want hide something? Maybe you need `git merge --squash`? Even so, the diff will have all changes anyway.

Comment: @kan Well, as I described in my original post, my goal is to compare a given feature branch, say `myFeature`, with the main `develop` branch. I'd like to perform a code review on the `myFeature` branch. If the developer of `myFeature` merged `develop` into it a few times (which is perfectly fine and encouraged), I'd like to not have to see all of the changes from `develop`, because (a) I've already reviewed them and (b) it just clouds up what is being changed in `myFeature`. I understand the theory behind `git merge`, I was just hoping that my use case is common and their was a workaround.

Comment: @doofuslarge I don't understand why you have problems. I've created a test repo. Yes, it shows two commits: the change and the merge, but it shows only changed files in the feature branch. Look here: https://github.com/kan-izh/harry-potter/pull/1/files

Comment: @kan Indeed you are right. Your example seems to contradict what I'm saying. I did some experiments of my own, and yes, the merge commit is shown, but the Files Changed tab only shows files changed on this feature branch. I'm not sure if GitHub has changed recently, or if I'm just crazy. Probably the latter. I'll update my original question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do it with rebase.

```
git checkout myFeature
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
git checkout develop
git merge @{upstream}
git merge myFeature # it will do fast-forward, so no merge commit
```

However, you should be aware, that rebase should be only used if the myFeature is not shared between other developers.

BTW, we are using gerrit. It allows to [rebase a changeset](http://aniszczyk.org/2012/11/26/gerrit-tip-rebase-change-button/) before merging. Of course if works only if there are no conflicts, if there are, you should do rebase locally and resubmit the changeset.