# Two commits appear in log for each merge

Tags: git, github

So I have been working on some small code changes, and pushing them to our `develop` branch (`master` is updated once a release is created).  Anyway, I'm noticing that once I merge any changes into the `develop` branch using "**Merge pull request**" in GitHub, doing a `git log` on develop shows me that there are two commits.  Here is a typical history of what I do.

1. From develop:
   `git checkout -b mylocalbranch develop`
2. Make my changes on my new branch, do an `add`, `commit` and `git push --set-upstream origin mylocalbranch`
3. Create my PR on GitHub (did steps 1-3 yesterday)
4. When all is cool, click on the "**Merge pull request**" button on the PR in GitHub, and delete the branch, also done through Github (did this step today).

Yet now, if I update `develop` and do a `git log`, I see something similar to the following:

```
commit b195f327fb7b80ebhfye5b6d17af6686tgs6dc79
Merge: d4c3f43 mwi6h80
Author: Meanwhile InHell <meanwhile@inhell.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 13 10:05:05 2016 +0100

    Merge pull request #666 from MWIH/mylocalbranch

    Updates to stuff that needed updated

commit mwi6h80664f09b95b8ce9xd3624435337259g47o
Author: Meanwhile InHell <meanwhile@inhell.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 12 16:54:05 2016 +0100

    Updates to stuff that needed updated
```

I don't understand why I have the first commit (the non-merge one) appearing on the `develop` branch.  I have a feeling its to do with the "`develop`" being present at the end of my branch creation; `git checkout -b mylocalbranch develop`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing merge commits in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561895/removing-merge-commits-in-git) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326381/is-there-a-way-to-hide-merge-commits-in-github-when-comparing-branches

Comment: I'm not looking to remove these commits as these tickets you linked are, I want to know why they have been created in the first place, as others in my company don't have this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in that case.

Comment: Perhaps its just my lack of git understanding (relatively new to it). I just figured that when merging into a `master` branch, there would only be that one commit for the merge.

Comment: Hence I linked the dupe: [You may be misunderstanding what information a merge commit represents. It's a marker that indicates where two branches became one in history, which is useful if you ever need to revert a particular merge (it gets complicated if you have to revert a fast-forward merge).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561895/removing-merge-commits-in-git#comment49195131_30561895)

Comment: Fair enough, I think you're probably right.

Answer (score 3):

If you do multiple commits you will see all of those commits in your development branch as they have been merged into development.

The merge itself counts as one commit as well, so you can see at what point a branch was merged.

There isn't really much more to it, unless you're wondering something else about it.

Comment: Exactly, the merge commit is such a commit which shows which HEAD of branches is connected. The merge command always introduce one extra commit. It gives possibility to revert the changes after merging with reverting only one singlu commit instead of all from external branch. To avoid one extra commit You can use rebase command.